# ANDROID AVD ERROR "bad config: virtual device file lacks a path entry"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

i have been dealing with this trouble for months beacuse i thaught the trauble was in my AMD a10 prcessor but this week i bought a ryzen 5 1600AF and the android emulator is still not working, when i try to launch it directly from android studio i get this error message "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_31 has terminated.", when i try to launch it from the terminal i get this error message "bad config: virtual device file lacks a path entry". There are some data that could be usefull to help me:

- hyper-V is disabled.
- Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver is installed.
- virtualization is enabled from BIOS.
- this is the way that my android files are distributed: [image]
- i have two enviroment variables related with android, JAVA_HOME to the openjdk-17 and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to the andoid-sdk folder you can see in the picture.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: No, i didn't, i recomend to use another emulator.